# Prime Number in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

Well I'm just completely new to Common Lisp programming language and I have started learning this language by my own from yesterday and that too out of interest.Now when i came across functions and loop,after learning about them I started developing the Prime Number problem in Common Lisp.
My code is as follows:

```
(defun prime (num)

(setq c 1)

(setq a 2)

(loop 

(setq a (+ 1 a))

(if (= (mod num a) 0)

(setq c (+ c 1))

)

(when (> (+ a 1) 17) (return a))

)
)

(if (= c 1)
(return-from prime num)
)
)

(loop for x from 1 to 20
do (prime x)
)
```

Now the problem which I am facing with this code is that whenever I am trying to execute this code the error which I am getting is as follows:

> ***IF: variable C has no value

but I've declared a value to c already still it's appearing. So all i want to know is that why this error is appearing even though i have declared it.

Comment: In any programming language you need to format and indent code to be readable. In Lisp, too. Please don't put unformatted code into questions.

Comment: @user242453 `(setq a (+ 1 a))`, can be replaced with `(incf a)`. Also there is a `1+` function for when writing `(+ 1 _)`

Answer (score 8):

When asking Emacs to reindent your code according to parenthesis depth, the cause of the error is immediately obvious:

```
(defun prime (num)
  (setq c 1)
  (setq a 2)
  (loop 
     (setq a (+ 1 a))
     (if (= (mod num a) 0)
     (setq c (+ c 1)))
     (when (> (+ a 1) 17) (return a))))
(if (= c 1)
    (return-from prime num)))
(loop for x from 1 to 20
   do (prime x))
```

As you can see, your `(if (= c 1) (return-from prime num))` is simply outside your `prime` function, and when it is eval'd as part of loading the file, it tries to eval `c`, which is indeed unbound as this is outside any scope where `c` is bound.

You may want to use an editor that can highlight parenthesis pairs in order to easier avoid these problems.

On another note, you may want to use `(let)` instead of `(setq)`, to give you proper lexical bindings. The way your program is currently written, `c` and `a` are essentially global variables.